# How to DOUBLE UP qoutes in text so that it is SQL friendly?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, reactjs, postgresql

When passing the text in SQL query that has qoutes (for example: I'm --text---) that ' in I'm needs to be doubled up so that server won't crash.

How to do that in javascript? Is there some NPM package or a way to loop through the text and double up the qoutes?

Here is my SQL text:

```
queryText = `INSERT INTO posts (id, user_id, title, content, image_urls) VALUES(uuid_generate_v4(), '${req.user.id}', '${title}', '${content}', ARRAY [${realImages}] ) RETURNING *`;
```

Comment:  [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I tested this and it worked for me:
( Just double quote beside the single ones )

```
queryText = INSERT INTO posts (id, user_id, title, content, image_urls) VALUES(uuid_generate_v4(), '"${req.user.id}"', '"${title}"', '${content}', ARRAY [${realImages}] ) RETURNING *;
```

P.S. Also one tip that I encounter, I think `uuid_generate_v4()` in your code should be `${uuid_generate_v4()}`, right?

Answer (score -1):

From what I understood, you want to double the quotes in a string.

The question now is: Do you want to transform simple quotes to double quotes, or do you want to double the amount of quotes?

The both cases will look like:

`'` -> `''`

`'` -> `"`

And for the worth cases you will need the function `replace`.

You can use it this way :

```js
let queryText = `INSERT INTO posts (id, user_id, title, content, image_urls) VALUES(uuid_generate_v4(), '${req.user.id}', '${title}', '${content}', ARRAY [${realImages}] ) RETURNING *`;

// First case
queryText  = queryText.replace(`'`, `''`);

// Second case
queryText  = queryText.replace(`'`, `"`);
```